# Getting all unique values between two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that has two fields that store the same type of information. I want to retrieve all unique values in those two fields.

If it were just one field I could do:

```
SELECT distinct FIELD1 FROM table
```

How can I get all unique values from FIELD1 and FIELD2

**Clarification**: 
I don't mean unique pairs.

Say field1 contains 1,13,5,25,13,8
and field2 contains 6,10,1,30,13

I want a query that returns 1,13,5,25,8,6,10,30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select distinct * FROM (
  select distinct field1 as n from table
    union 
  select distinct field2 as n from table) as t;
```

Comment: I think it might be more efficient to apply `distinct` only once, on the outside query.

Comment: It depends on your data and mainly on amount of non-unique values for each field.

Comment: With a simple subquery, perhaps, but isn't the `union` operator already eliminating duplicates in your subquery? Perhaps a better way to word my question is "Is it more efficient to explicitly use `distinct` or to let `union` handle it?" (It may be different for other dbs, but the OP is asking about MySQL so it's probably enough just to know how it works here.)

Comment: You are right, union already eliminate duplicates.
I think union deed it more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  field1 ,field2 FROM tablename group by field1 ,field2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select field1 from table
union 
select field2 from table
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer? I downvoted you because I'd missed something in the question, and of course now that it seems to me your answer is the best, I can't change my vote, and I don't have the rep to edit your answer myself.

Comment: No problem. I'll survive the same. Bye :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean all unique pairs? Then this might do (a bit dirty, though):

```
SELECT distinct CONCAT(FIELD1, '|', FIELD2) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a union of two sql statements:

```
Select distinct FIELD1 From table
UNION
Select distinct FIELD2 From table
```